# Passing less variables from webpack

Tags: javascript, less, webpack

I'm trying to pass less variables within a webpack configuration to the less loader, naturally. 
For some reason the variable is not being passed ok. I can't figure the correct syntax.

The variable has a dynamic content that is determined at the build time, in the webpack config file. This is the relevant line (I've tried many variations of it):

```
loader: 'style!css?-minimize!less?-minimize&{modifyVars:{"resources-path-prefix":"' + pathPrefix + '"}}'
```

In the above example some pathPrefix is being determined at build time and we want to pass its value into less context, where it will be used in url() css directives.

The above doesn't work - nothing is passed into less, and the default variable value defined in less applies.

Can anyone show how to correctly pass the value into the less compilation process? Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual variable in less `@resources-path-prefix` or `resources-path-prefix`? I think you are missing the `@` which is expected in `modifyVars`.

Comment: In the less its @resources-path-prefix (as less variables should be declared)

Comment: Ah whoops looks like the modifyVars accepts both with or without the @ symbol. Thought that might have been missing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So it was tough but we **finally** made it work(!). Arggh - so much time invested to trying and figure out the syntax.

Here's the task: we want at build time to determine a path that should use used as the base url for misc assets in less files (background images, using url() less function).

First, we determined the path in webpack config file. Its plain JS, but the escaping pattern for the path string was absolutely nuts. We probably invested **hours** just on this. **Amazing**. Here it is:

```
var assetsPath = (someCondition) ? '/assets' : "\\/127.0.0.1:8080/assets";
```

Next is the loader configuration for less files, using the assetsPath prefix set above:

```
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'style!css?minimize=false!less?{"modifyVars":{"assetspath":"\'' + assetsPath +'\'"}}'
}
```

Notice the escaping pattern above where using the assetsPath in the loader configuration.

Next, you need to make sure that an empty variable is being defined in the less files. We initialized it in our 'vars.less' file, with:

```
@assetspath: '';
```

Finally, in any relevant class, we can use the value being passed in build time like this:

```
background-image: url("@{assetspath}/images/facebook.png");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can *try* to use the `query` section of the loader:

```
    loader: 'style!css?-minimize!less?-minimize',
    query: {
        modifyVars: {
           "resources-path-prefix": pathPrefix
        } 
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the swift response. However, that's not possible. You can't use this syntax with multiple loaders... . You immediately get: "Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list" (just tested it).

Comment: Ahh. got it. Consider instead using less as a separate loader after the other ones.

Comment: but the above uses 3 chained loaders - less, css and style (in that order). Do I need to mimic the 'linkage' in the separate mode somehow? (and if so, how?).

Comment: Make a loader for just `style!css?-minimize`, then another 2nd one just for `less?-minimize`, I believe webpack loads them in order.

Comment: Tried. Separate loaders works but the less loader fails. I'm down to this:

  query: {
          modifyVars: {
            "resourcespathprefix": resourcesPathPrefix
          }
        }

I've refactored the less file so the variable name would be all-small-letters (one less camel casing problem to consider). Still no-go, I get:
Module build failed: Unrecognised input
...
near lines:
   }
   @resourcespathprefix: http://127.0.0.1:8080/;

It appears to me as if the variable interpolated value is missing commas but I cannot seem to find how to add them :-( Tried multiple syntaxes

Answer (score 1):

It's a different approach to this situation, but we managed to make things work by converting into Base64 every resource that the CSS files loaded. We had to do this because figuring out the hostname of the resources was possible much later down the line than the webpack config file.