# Dynamic theming using less in webpack angular application

Tags: angularjs, webpack, less, theming

I have built a angular webpack application and want to theme the application completely based on the REST API response (theme data - colors).

I am using a global less file which is used across the application pages.
I'm using

```
less.modifyVars({"variableName":"Value"}) ;
less.refresh();
```

in the controller and the call is working but the less variables are not changing and reflecting in pages.

I observer that its because the less files are already compiled to css when the controller is loaded and these less variables are not accessible dynamically.

Can anyone suggest any other approach or what i'm missing here? and how i can change the less variable before its compiles into css by the webpack. Or rather recompiles the less again to take the latest values form the api without reloading the page.

Please NOTE : im using npm to install all  dependency and less is loaded from package json , and console.log(less) in the controller says less is undefined at client.

Thanks,

Comment: can anyone suggest something on this , awaiting to move ahead:)

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/38382962/5064575

Comment: this one is static one , but i have to get the values from the api and one which works with authentication , and as i know i cant call a pi in web.config.js file , am i right?

Comment: Well, technically you could, but I don't think you would want to do an API call in your web.config file. The problem is that a .less file is processed to a .css file during build, not runtime, so changing the .less variables does nothing. Maybe `less.refreshStyles();` is what you need? That method recompiles .less files at runtime when using `<style type="text/less">`. Otherwise, my own solution would probably to write a method that does the call and uses jQuery to update the elements' css attribute.

Comment: hi @RickvanOsta  : Thanks , yes i think that <style type="text/less"> will work but pint here is that browser will not understand the less and also webpack doesnt run without any loader conversions.   less.refreshStyles(); is not working have tried it.                                              I have tried the second suggestion using Jquery , but i think that is not feasable as it has to be done on every module and inline styling.            in this case less written  is completley unseful :(

Comment: That is true. Webpack ruins a lot of cool stuff. Maybe you can alter the less  exported global .css file using jQuery? Just a suggestion though.

Comment: that would be same again , will try other options  before concluding on the jqeury usage,  however i just saw a package "js-to-styles-var-loader" which seems to take the variables form js , can u give inputs on this?    https://github.com/tompascall/js-to-styles-var-loader

Comment: Hmm, looks sort of promising. Though I fear that it will only insert the data once, and when you try to edit it afterwards it won't insert it again. But you should try out the small demo project they have in the demo folder on the repo. You might figure out if it fits your needs.

Comment: yep iv seen that , will look at the options to modify it.

Comment: anyone else could suggest something on this? it will be  abig help

Comment: @Dpk_Gopi Hey did you find out the way to do this ? I'm also facing same issue.